# Created a duplicate text in same canvas but the second doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

They have the exact same lines of code too but the second one doesn't work. The first countdown is supposed to run when the game first starts and the second whenever there's a battle going on.

Here's the first which works as intended:

```
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime=0f;
    float startingTime=5f;
    public string outcome; //This will be the outcome of the random roll that will decide who attacks first

    [SerializeField] Text countdownText;

    void Awake()
    {

        currentTime = startingTime; //setting current time to 5
        System.Random rand = new System.Random(); //choses a random number between 0 and 1
        if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0) 
        {
            outcome = "Player 1 Attacks First";
        }

        else
        {
            outcome = "Player 2 Attacks First";
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (currentTime > 3.5)
        {
            Timer();
            countdownText.text = outcome; // Displays the player that starts attacking firtst

        }
        if (currentTime > 0.5&& currentTime<3.5) //Starts the timer from 3
        {
            Timer();
            countdownText.text = currentTime.ToString("0");
        }


            if (currentTime < 0.5)
            {
            Timer();
            countdownText.text = "GO";
            }

            if (currentTime < -0.5)
            {
            countdownText.text = "";
            this.enabled = false;
            }


    }
    void Timer()
    {
        currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

And here's the second, it just displays "0":

```
public class CountdownInBattle : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime = 0f;
    float startingTime = 5f;
    [SerializeField] Text countdownText2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;
        //if (GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Countdown>().enabled == true)
        //{
        //    this.enabled = false;
        //}
        Debug.Log("Starting Countdown");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentTime > 0.5 && currentTime < 3.5) //Starts the timer from 3
        {
            Timer();
            countdownText2.text = currentTime.ToString("0");
        }


        if (currentTime < 0.5)
        {
            Timer();
            countdownText2.text = "GO";
        }

        if (currentTime < -0.5)
        {
            countdownText2.text = "";
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void Timer()
    {
        currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

This one is supposed to run every time there's a battle happening, but it doesn't work at all. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `currentTime` to `5f` at start.

So none of your conditions in `Update`

```
if (currentTime > 0.5 && currentTime < 3.5) //Starts the timer from 3
{
    Timer();
    countdownText2.text = currentTime.ToString("0");
}


if (currentTime < 0.5)
{
    Timer();
    countdownText2.text = "GO";
}

if (currentTime < -0.5)
{
    countdownText2.text = "";
    this.enabled = false;
}
```

ever matches -> nothing happens.

In the first script you had an additional condition for

```
if (currentTime > 3.5)
{
    Timer();
    countdownText.text = outcome; // Displays the player that starts attacking firtst
}
```

so quick fix would be to either increase that first condition to

```
if (currentTime > 0.5 && currentTime <= 5) //Starts the timer from 5
```

or to move the call of `Timer();` outside of the conditions since it should be called **every** frame unconditional

---

I would strongly recommend to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that so you can simply use the same component for both things:

```
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text _countdownText2;

    public UnityEvent OnCountdownFinished;

    public void StartCountdown(int forSeconds)
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting Countdown");
        StartCoroutine(DoCountdown(forSeconds));
    }

    private IEnumerator DoCountdown(int forSeconds)
    {
        int seconds = forSeconds;
        while (seconds > 0)
        {
            // yield means return to the main thread, render the frame
            // and continue this method from this point
            // in the next frame

            // waitForSeconds does as it says ... repeat this return until X seconds have past
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            // reduce seconds by one
            seconds--;

            // update the text
            _countdownText2.text = seconds.ToString();
        }

        // when done call the callbacks you added
        OnCountdownFinished.Invoke();
    }
}
```

`OnCountdownFinished` is a [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) and works just like the `onClick` of buttons so you can simply execute any callback method when the countdown is finished.

and than add a callback either in the Inspector or you could set it all up from script like

```
public class FightController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerialiteField] private int _secondsDisplayName;
    [SerializeField] private int _secondsBeforeFight;
    [SerializeField] private int _secondsInFight;

    [SerializeField] private Countdown _beforeCountdown;
    [SerializeField] private Countdown _inFightcountdown;    

    public string outcome;

    private void Awake()
    {
        System.Random rand = new System.Random(); //choses a random number between 0 and 1
        if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0) 
        {
            outcome = "Player 1 Attacks First";
        }
        else
        {
            outcome = "Player 2 Attacks First";
        }

        // and display the random outcome
        // there is no need to update this every frame
        countdownText.text = outcome;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // add a callback what should happen after the first countdown -> start the second
        _beforeCountdown.OnCountdownFinished.AddListener(StartInFightCountdown);

       // maybe also already add the callback what should happen after the second one

       // Now since you want to display the random name for
       // the first two seconds simply use a routine again:
       StartCoroutine(Prepare());
    }

    private IEnumerator Prepare()
    {
        // wait the two seonds, than begin the before countdown at 3
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_secondsDisplayName);

        // than start the first countdown
        _beforeCountdown.StartCountdown(_secondsBeforeFight);
    }

    private void StartInFightCountdown()
    {
        _inFightcountdown.StartCountdown(_secondsInFight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm an absolute newbie so I don't know how coroutines work.